# mmenu.js doesn't work on TYPO3 after upgrading it (mmenu) from 8.5 to 9.1 (or 9.3)

Tags: typo3, mmenu

I have a typo3 project which uses mmenu in order to create a hamburger menu after a certain screen-size (smaller than 980px).

mmenu v8.5 works perfectly, but with mmenu v9.3, the additional menu (which  is supposed to be hidden) is visible in all screen-sizes and also all the menus (nav menu at the top and the mmenu on the left) are unclickable. The left menu covers half the screen on the left.

I have unfortunately no error message. The only difference, I noticed with the old version is: the second menu has an id of mm-my-menu in the working old version but it is mm-clone-my-menu in the broken menu.

I changed the attributes on inspect screen in order to find out the problem but it changes nothing. I'm new with TYPO3 and I'll be really thankful after any help or suggestion.

Comment: This sounds more like an issue of mmenu's upgrade path... There's a discussion on that on https://github.com/FrDH/mmenu-js/issues/1264 . TYPO3 is only used for generating the HTML. So you have to find out what has changed in mmenu to output the appropriate HTML - or reconfigure mmenu to what it sounds like on github.

Comment: Thanks for the link but it didn't help a lot. I'm new with typo3 and I don't know where to start or check to find the reason of such menu-behaviour. Maybe the reason is the wrappers but I don't know how to fix? Any suggestion where to check?

Comment: mmenu is not part of TYPO3. Therefore, it strongly depends on your instance or integration where/how mmenu has been integrated. A best practice is that there is a sitepackage as an extension, and the HTML for mmenu can be found in it. But as I said, this depends on your site and can be solved individually.